# C# Navigating JSON structure nest returning NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using the OpenLibrary API to gather information on books from their ISBN number
I have created a simple JSON setup, but can't get it to retrieve values from nested structures.

The link to the JSON is: http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0747532699&jscmd=details&format=json

I am trying to access the "title" value. In this case, it should return: `Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone`

My code is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the ISBN: ");
String isbn = Console.ReadLine();
String url = "http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&jscmd=details&format=json";
String json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken details = jsonObject["ISBN:" + isbn + ".details"];
String title = (string) details["title"];
Console.WriteLine(title);
```

The error is a System.NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) which is caused on the line `JToken details = jsonObject["ISBN:" + isbn + ".details"];`

I have seen on other questions to use the . character to go through the structure, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `SelectToken()` and your code will work.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the ISBN: ");
String isbn = "0747532699";
String url = "http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&jscmd=details&format=json";
String json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken details = jsonObject.SelectToken("ISBN:" + isbn + ".details");
String title = (string)details["title"];
Console.WriteLine(title);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly now.